# How do I boot into UEFI without going through Windows on my laptop?

Tags: windows, bios, bootloader, uefi, mbr

So I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 8 laptop in a dual-boot configuration for some time, and tonight, I decided I would uninstall Ubuntu. Well, I've managed to lock myself out of Windows and I'm stuck at a GRUB prompt without Ubuntu without access to my Windows partition. I have a flash drive ready with software to fix my MBR, but I don't know how to boot into it without getting access to a boot menu of some kind, and I don't know what keys to push to get to the BIOS.

I'm currently at a GRUB 2.02 prompt on my Acer Aspire V5-573P-9899. It doesn't have a CD drive, but I do have my flash drive and another computer handy.

Thank you for your help. All I need to do is get into a boot menu and I (hopefully) can take it from there.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try pressing "Del" on splash screen to get into the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Some laptop and notebook computers have an option in the BIOS/UEFI to activate the hotkey. This means that the F1 .. F12 will act now as Vol+, Vol-, Mute, Play, Stop, etc. In order to access the functionality of the traditional function you would have to hold the Fn key while pressing the F key (for Example Fn+F5 to refresh the current Window).

If this is the case you would have to hit Fn+F2 or Fn+10 before Windows boots up.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I did it! I had to tap F2 as the computer was booting instead of just holding it like I was doing. Silly me.